# How can I write a function definition which gets another function as parameter whether the parameters of the function match a pattern?

Tags: argument-patterns, parameters

One can write functions which depend on the type of actual parameter before they are actually called. E.g.:

```
Clear[f,g,DsQ];
DsQ[x_]:=MatchQ[x,{String__}];
f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ] :=Print["called with integer i and DsQ[ds]==True"];
f[i_String, ds_?DsQ]  :=Print["called with String i and DsQ[ds]==True"];
f[i_?NumberQ, ds_?DsQ]:=Print["called with numerical parameter"];
f[i_?NumberQ]:=Print["only a numerical parameter"];

(* Tests *)
ds={"string"};
DsQ[ds]
f[1,ds]
f[1.,{""}]
f[999]
```

yields

```
True
called with integer i and DsQ[ds]==True
called with numerical parameter
only a numerical parameter
```

Now I want to write another function `g`, which gets a function like `f` as parameter. But the functional parameter’s definition’s left hand side shall have a defined form, e.g. only the one from the first definition of `f`

```
f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]
```

Is such a check for the right pattern of a functional parameter possible?
How do I do that? Writing

```
g[p_Symbol[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]]:=Print["g called with first type of definition"]
```

does not work.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you want to achieve: How do you want to call `g`? As `g[f]`? What should happen if `f` has multiple different definitions (like in your example)? What do you ultimately want to use this for?

Comment: I think what you want is to set attributes of `g` so that it holds its argument. Something like `SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]`.  Try it out and see if it works: `g[f[1, {""}]]` prints "g called with first type of definition" but `g[f[0.1, {""}]]` returns unevaluated. If that's what you want, I can write a quick answer.

Comment: I agree with @LukasLang that this looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you could describe in detail what you are trying to achieve (at high level), then you’ll likely get better answers.

Comment: Since you tried `g[p_Symbol[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]]` instead of `g[f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]]`, I'm inferring that what you mean by "type" is something like *signature*. Is that correct? I.e. the function `g` doesn't actually know about the function `f` explicitly, but will do something for any `p` that has a particular *signature*. If this is on the right track, it would be very helpful to have more context. What do you need `g` to do with `p` and with the arg pattern?

Comment: I ask, because as it stand, I don't think you can come up with something generally resilient. For example, one can't expect `f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]` to be a sort of canonical form for that signature. Indeed, something like `f[i_Integer, ds : {__String}]` might be more expected.

Comment: Side note. `DsQ[x_] := MatchQ[x, {String__}]` is probably not what you wanted in the first place. Note that `DsQ[{5}]` yields `True`.

Comment: Question from the first comment: I am dealing with data structures. Once they are read into Mma, I perform operations on them (filtering out subsets, joining, intersecting,..). I already have a framework of such functions. Some come in several flavors: operating on a file, operating on a list of files, operating on a file and a data structure... They differ in how their input is presented. I want to plug in different functions `f` to compute final results. To prevent plugging one with the wrong structure, I want  type checking for the type of parameters of the plugged-in function `f`.

Comment: Of course the different functions to be plugged in as parameter to `g` will will have different names, but the types of arguments to them are always the same.

Comment: What about just trying to evaluate `f[args1]`, and if nothing happens (i.e. `f` doesn't have a definition matching those arguments), try `f[args2]`, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These examples show better which expression causes a specific print line than in my original post:

```
ClearAll[f,g,DsQ];
DsQ[x_]:=MatchQ[x,{String__}];

f[x___] := (Print["f: called with illegal arguments f[", x, "]"]; Abort[]);   (* added catch all, tx Roman *)
f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ] := (Print["f: called with integer ", i, 
" and DsQ[ds]==True"]; "Result: "<>ToString[i]<>", "<>ToString[ds]);
f[s_String, ds_?DsQ]  := (Print["f: called with String ", s, " and DsQ[ds]==True"]; "Result: "<>s<>", "<>ToString[ds]);

(* Tests *)
ds={"string ds"};
DsQ[ds]
f[1, ds]
f["hello", ds]
```

yields

```
True

f: called with illegal arguments f[forbidden!]
$Aborted

f: called with integer 1 and DsQ[ds]==True
Result: 1,{string ds}

f: called with String hello and DsQ[ds]==True
Result: hello, {string ds}
```

The other function `g` gets a function like the first form of `f` as parameter. The functional parameter’s definition’s left hand side shall have a defined form, e.g. only the one from the first definition of `f`

```
f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]
```

and not e.g. the other way around like

```
h1[ds_?DsQ, i_Integer]
```

or

```
h2[i_Integer, j_Integer]
```

or any form of f but the first one.

This is the appropriate pattern for the functional parameter on the LHS:

```
g[p_Symbol[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ]]:=Print["g: called with first type of definition, f returns ", f[i, ds]];
```

In this one

```
g[f[3, {"three"}]]
```

`f` is evaluated first and returns a string. We see the `Print` from `f` and the unevaluated expression of `g` with the result from `f` which does not match `g`'s definition pattern, therefore we get:

```
g[Result: {three}]]
```

But after setting `HoldAll` it works:

```
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]
g[f[4, {"four"}]]
```

It prints

```
f: called with integer 4 and DsQ[ds]==True
g: called with first type of definition, f returns Result: 4, {four}
```

which is what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The call patterns are stored under the name of "DownValues":

```
DownValues[f]
```

[image]

Therefore, the part that determines the type can be extracted by:

```
DownValues[f][[1, 1, 1, 2]]
```

[image]

and you can define g e.g. like:

```
g[i_ : Integer, DownValues[f][[1, 1, 1, 2]] ] := 
 Print["g called with integer and string-list"]

g[1, {"y"}]
(* g called with integer and string-list *)
```

Comment: Daniel, somehow you mistyped something which prevents me from seeing the clue which was about to follow your last colon.

Comment: Sorry, I added the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion that differs from your approach but may be useful. For every function (here, `f` and `h`) we define a "correct" interface and a "catchall" interface that is used whenever the function is called incorrectly. The "catchall" interface (with the pattern `x___`) [aborts the running calculation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abort.html).

```
Clear[f, g, h, DsQ];
DsQ[x_] := MatchQ[x, {String__}];

f[i_Integer, ds_?DsQ] := Print["f called with integer i and DsQ[ds]==True"];
f[x___] := Module[{},
             Print["f called with different arguments: ", {x}];
             Abort[]]

h[i_Integer] := Print["h called with integer i"];
h[x___] := Module[{},
             Print["h called with different arguments: ", {x}];
             Abort[]]

g[p_Symbol] := p[7, {"a"}] + p[8, {"b"}] + p[9, {"c"}]
```

We can use `f` to call the function `g`:

```
g[f]
(*    f called with integer i and DsQ[ds]==True
      f called with integer i and DsQ[ds]==True
      f called with integer i and DsQ[ds]==True
      3 Null                                       *)
```

But we're not allowed to use `h` to call the function `g`:

```
g[h]
(*    called with different arguments: {7,{a}}
      $Aborted                                     *)
```

Of course your action in the "catchall" may be different from `Abort[]`.